Nginx "File not found." error
I have already read all similar topics but wasn't able to fix the issue so I posted here :
I can run a PHP file on SSH Terminal successfully :
root@skins:~/public1# php8.3 /root/public1/public/index.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='http://:/requirement#'" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://:/requirement#</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://:/requirement#">http://:/requirement#</a>.
    </body>

However , I can't run the same file in browser and I get Nginx File not found error .
Here is my Nginx site.conf :
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name some.domain.com;
    root /root/public1/public; ##<----THIS IS THE ACTUAL PATH 
 
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
 
    index index.php;
 
    charset utf-8;
 
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
 
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
 
    error_page 404 /index.php;
 
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
    }
 
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

In the Nginx error log I have the following :
2024/12/25 13:55:05 [crit] 74930#74930: *5 stat() "/root/public1/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.198.213.143, server: some.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "some.domain.com"
2024/12/25 13:55:05 [crit] 74930#74930: *5 stat() "/root/public1/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.198.213.143, server: some.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "some.domain.com"
2024/12/25 13:55:05 [crit] 74930#74930: *5 realpath() "/root/public1/public" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.198.213.143, server: some.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "some.domain.com"
2024/12/25 13:55:05 [error] 74930#74930: *5 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 88.198.213.143, server: some.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock:", host: "some.domain.com"
2024/12/25 13:55:05 [error] 74930#74930: *5 open() "/root/public1/public/favicon.ico" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.198.213.143, server: some.domain.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "some.domain.com", referrer: "http://some.domain.com/"

Can anyone help what is wrong with my Nginx configuration?

Have you read your logs? It says in plain English what the problem is. Second, don't host things in /root/. In general I'd suggest learning the Linux distro you're using before attempting more complex tasks such as running servers.

Your nginx configuration sets the site's root directory in a directory that the nginx user (www-data) does not have permission to access.
Change the nginx root directory to a location that www-data has permission to access.
For example:
root /var/www/html;

Is a common root directory location.

the issue is solved but previously I ran a command to add www-data user to root group . how do I undo this? gpasswd -a www-data root

Use the -d option: gpasswd -d www-data root.

The error message is clear: Nginx does not have permission to access the file. Which makes sense: /root is the home directory of the root user – nobody except the root user should have access to it, certainly not a web server that is exposed to remote attacks.
The simple solution is to move the file somewhere the user the Nginx web server is running under (presumable some Ngninx service user) has access to.
In Ubuntu, by default, Nginx runs under the www-data user. So, you can create a directory for use by Nginx something like this:
sudo mkdir -p /srv/www/nginx/public1/public
sudo chown -R root:www-data /srv/www/nginx
sudo chmod -R 0750 /srv/www

This will give root read/write access, Nginx read access, and everybody else no access at all.
